# Add list item returning empty result

Tags: list, javascript, item

Hi Sharepoint experts,

I'm trying to add list item using jsom and succeeded but my code keeps adding empty list item first.

```
    function repeat(pattern, count) {
        if (count < 1) return '';
        var result = '';
        while (count > 1) {
            if (count & 1) result += pattern;
            count >>= 1, pattern += pattern;
        }
        return result + pattern;
    }

    function onCountSucceeded() {
        varNoPR = '';
        varListCnt = oList.get_itemCount();
        if (varListCnt === 0) {
            varListCnt = 1;
        }
        else {
            varListCnt += 1;
        }
        varTmpStr = varListCnt.toString();
        varStrLen = varTmpStr.length;
        varNoPR = repeat('0', 10 - varStrLen).concat(varTmpStr);
     }

    function getLastNumber() {
        var clientContext2 = new SP.ClientContext(varsiteUrl);
        this.oList = clientContext2.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        clientContext2.load(this.oList);    
        clientContext2.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCountSucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );    
    }

    function createItem() {  
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(varsiteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
        oListItem.set_item('NoPR', varNoPR);
        oListItem.update();

        clientContext.load(oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onAddItemSucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );
    }

    function createListItem() {
        getLastNumber();
        createItem();
    }
```

So my goal is inserting custom auto increment number by counting the list items first and then add '0' so the resulting number becomes '0000000001', ...etc.
But when I run this twice (I assigned this code to button), it resulted in empty item, and then item 0000000001.
What I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the calls are async, so you should make sure `getLastNumber()` is done before you call `createItem()`. This could be done in diferrent ways, but an easy route is to use jQuerys [$.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object.

An simple example based on your getLastNumber and createListItem:

```
function getLastNumber() {
        this.dfd = $.Deferred();

        var clientContext2 = new SP.ClientContext(varsiteUrl);
        this.oList = clientContext2.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        clientContext2.load(this.oList);    
        clientContext2.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCountSucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );    

        return this.dfd.promise();
    }

   function onCountSucceeded() {
    varNoPR = '';
    varListCnt = oList.get_itemCount();
    if (varListCnt === 0) {
        varListCnt = 1;
    }
    else {
        varListCnt += 1;
    }
    varTmpStr = varListCnt.toString();
    varStrLen = varTmpStr.length;
    varNoPR = repeat('0', 10 - varStrLen).concat(varTmpStr);

    this.dfd.resolve();
 }


      function createListItem() {
         getLastNumber().done(function() {
           createItem();
        });     
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I will try it and inform you guys the result..

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the SharePoint SE!

This behavior occurs since [SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is an *async* method. 
Hence you cant call your methods sequentially like this:

```
getLastNumber();
createItem();
```

but have to wait until `succeededCallback` function will be invoked and only then execute the next request.

When working with asynchronous API such as JSOM the following patterns are commonly used:

- Using nested callbacks
- Using the promises pattern

Please refer [Asynchronous programming in apps for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220067%28v=office.15%29.aspx) article to get acquainted with asynchronous programming for SharePoint.

The below example is converted version of your example using callback approach:

```
function repeat(pattern, count) {
        if (count < 1) return '';
        var result = '';
        while (count > 1) {
            if (count & 1) result += pattern;
            count >>= 1, pattern += pattern;
        }
        return result + pattern;
}




function getNextNumber(listTitle,OnSuccess,OnError) {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    context.load(list);    
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
               var nextIdStr = (list.get_itemCount() + 1).toString();
               var nextNoPR = repeat('0', 10 - nextIdStr.length).concat(nextIdStr);
               OnSuccess(nextNoPR);
        },
        OnError
    );    
}





function addListItem(listTitle,itemProps,OnItemAdded,OnItemFailed)
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();

    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    for(var propName in itemProps) {
       listItem.set_item(propName, itemProps[propName]) 
    }

    listItem.update();
    context.load(listItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          OnItemAdded(listItem);           
        },
        OnItemFailed
    );
}
```

Usage

```
var listTitle = 'Requests';
getNextNumber(listTitle,
  function(nextNoPR){
      //console.log(nextNoPR);

      var itemProperties  = {'Title': 'New request','NoPR':nextNoPR};
      addListItem(listTitle,itemProperties,
         function(item){   
            console.log(item.get_item('NoPR'));
         },
         function(sender,args){
            console.log(args.get_message());
         }
      );
  },
  function(sender,args){
      console.log('An error corrured while getting next NoPR:' + args.get_message());
  }
);
```

Comment: this one works too. but I can't use SP.ClientContext.get_current(). I kept my new SP.ClientContext(varsiteUrl) to make it work.